# How to retry an json API request after a timeout using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

I've been trying to loop through multiple API request and parsing the data to put into a dataframe.  When running the script it occasionally timeouts and I got the following output: **{'Message': 'Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.'}**.  When that happens the script fails because I get a value since this can't be input in the dataframe so the following error appears: **ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index** I tried the following code below  but I'm still receiving the errors occasionally. I tried to use the while block to check for the timeout and then retry again if it appears but unfortunately that didn't work. Is there any exception handling or other way I can deal with the timeout error that appears sometimes?

```
for id in list:
    
        t=0
        x = requests.get('json.api'.format(id)).json()
        print(x)
        while t < 5:
           if 'Timeout' in x:
               "{} json timed out. Trying again".format(id)
               x = requests.get('json.api'.format(id)).json()
               t+=1
           else:
                t = 5
        name = pd.DataFrame( index =[0]).from_dict(x)
```

Comment: Is the URL correct? you need to add either `http://` or `https://` depending whether it's applicable or not.

Comment: Yeah it works correctly, it pulls the data fine but occasionally it times out, so the script only works part of the time.  I'm just trying to get it to retry the same request when the timeout message appears.

Comment: You can use `celery` and configure retries as required

Comment: would you mind providing an example? I'm not too familiar with celery

Answer (score 0):

Here, you go.

It's kind of overkill if your task is too small, you need to set up RabbitMQ as a message broker. Refer [Celery Documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) for more details.

```
   (celery_task.py)

   import pandas as pd
   import requests
   from celery import Celery 
   from celery.exceptions import MaxRetriesExceededError, Retry

   app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')


   @app.task(bind=True, max_retries=100, autoretry_for=(Exception,))
   def loop():
      try:
        """
        do some calc
        """
        for id in list:
            t = 0
            x = requests.get('json.api'.format(id)).json()
            print(x)
            name = pd.DataFrame(index=[0]).from_dict(x)
            """
            do some calc
            """
            
    except MaxRetriesExceededError as max_retry:
        print(max_retry)
```

Triggering mechanism

```
python
>>> from celery_task import app
>>> app.send_task("tasks.<name your task>", (<enter all the parameterss required to run the task>))
```